Install a package without pip
I have Python 3.12.3 [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.
The connection to servers is blocked on my network so i can't use pip to install packages but I can go to https://pypi.org to download wheel file or .tar.gz file.
The other problem is that I don't have the wheel module so i can't use the command python -m wheel install package.whl.
I downloaded wheel-0.43.0.tar.gz, unzipped then in the folder i do the command: python setup.py install then i get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

If you don't have pip either for whichever reason, download and run the https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py script on the target machine.

How exactly would you run a 64 bit Pyhon on a 32 bit system?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The sys.platform name for all Windowses regardless of bitness is win32.

Certainly, but then they need to [edit] their post to say which windows they're actually on.

@Mike if python 64-bit runs, it's not on 32-bit Windows.

You can still use pip without server access.
Put the downloads in a directory, cd to that directory, then python -m pip install --no-index -f . <package_name1> [package_name2...].  --no-index prevents going to the network to look for the pypi package index, and -f . (short for --find-links) looks in the current directory for packages.
If you have a system that does have access to the network, use python -m pip download <package> and it will also download any dependencies.  Then transfer them to the system that doesn't have network access (or at least now you know all the dependencies).

Note that the machine you use python -m pip download ... on must be the same OS, architecture and Python version, or you'll have to fiddle with the --python-version, --implementation, --abi and --platform flags in order to get the correct binary packages.
